# React - Passing props to App.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Recently I learned how to pass props from one component to another. In my case, from `<FileTree>` to `<TextBox>`, as you can see here: **https://codesandbox.io/s/y018010qk9**

But after, I reorganized the code a bit and now it is possible to see the structure of my React App inside `<App> (App.js)`. I decided to put the `<FileTree>` and `<TextBox>` side by side, with Bootstrap.

So, logically I thought that passing `props` from `<App>` to `<TextBox>` would be the same as I did before: From `<FileTree>` to `<TextBox>`. Unfortunatelly, it is not the case.

At the moment, this is the code inside `<App>`:

```
// Structure of the project
export class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <div className="col-md-12">
            <SearchEngine />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <FileTree />
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-6">
            <TextBox content={this.props.activeNode} />
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}
}
```

And here, the code inside `<TextBox>`:

```
// TextBox component
export class TextBox extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        content: 'Select A Node To See Its Data Structure Here...'
    }
    this.showContent = this.showContent.bind(this);
}

showContent (newContent) {
    this.setState ({
        content: newContent
    })
}

componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    this.setState ({
        content: nextProps.content
    })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div className="padd_top">
      <div className="content_box">{this.state.content}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default TextBox;
```

Just in case, here one can find the `<FileTree> component`:

```
// Construction of FileTree
export class FileTree extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeNode: null
    }
    this.setActiveNode = this.setActiveNode.bind(this);
  }

  setActiveNode(name) {
    this.setState({activeNode: name})
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div className="padd_top">{
        renderTree(
          this.props.root || root, 
          this.setActiveNode, 
          this.state.activeNode
          )
        }  
      </div>
    )
  }  
}
```

**I'm recently getting to know React.js** and I'm very thankful for any advice/clarity you can provide.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting the value of  `this.props.activeNode` from?

Comment: Can you provide the code inside your ReactDOM.render method?

Comment: @Liam, check the code in the link: **https://codesandbox.io/s/y018010qk9**

Comment: @HarishSoni, this link provides all the code: **https://codesandbox.io/s/y018010qk9**

Comment: Where are your FileTree and TextBox components?

Comment: Why are you importing TextBox in App file and index file?

Comment: @HarishSoni, inside the link I provided, you can find the `<FileTree />` inside `index.js` component from line `105`

Comment: @Liam, forgive me. I forgot to remove `<TextBox>` inside `index.js`. It is supposed to be used only inside `App.js`.

Comment: and where is the search-engine.js?

Comment: and also the FileTree is not in the index.js

Comment: @HarishSoni, `<SearchEngine>` is not being used at the moment and the `<FileTree>` **component** is inside `index.js`, line `105`.

Comment: Your parent file is index not App, you are not calling App file as well TextBox file

Comment: @Liam, aaah yes! I just noticed I was focusing on the file `index.js`. I changed the code a bit: **https://codesandbox.io/s/y018010qk9** why it is not rendering?

Comment: @Liam, in my side the `App.js` structure is working okay, it's just the passing props from `<App>` to `<TextBox>` that is not working properly. Maybe in CodeSandbox doesn't work for some other reason?

Comment: Yes I see that but I'm seeing also index file doesn't work with App file

Comment: I'm getting a white screen

Comment: @Liam, maybe switch code between `App.js` and `ìndex.js` might work in CodeSandbox.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169940/discussion-between-rcohen-and-liam).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use lift state method passing state from child to parent then from parent pass it to the child you want

In your parent component create a constructor with states then create `liftStateUp` function pass it to the child component that you want to receive the data from

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeNode: '',
    }
  }

  liftStateUp = (data) =>{
    this.setState({ activeNode: data})
  }

  <div>
    <div className="col-md-6">
      <FileTree liftStateUp={this.liftStateUp} />
    </div>
    <div className="col-md-6">
      <TextBox content={this.state.activeNode} />
    </div>
  </div>
```

Then in **file_tree.js** `FileTree` function you need to call `liftStateUp` function that we created it in the parent component

```
  setActiveNode(name) {
    this.setState({ activeNode: name });
    this.props.liftStateUp(name);
  }
```

[image: Edit ypj786pv59]

https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 0):

Props are passed down from the parent component to child component. You need to work with global store so that you can interact with state in different siblings of components. For this, you may use [redux](https://redux.js.org/).

If your application size is smaller, then you may also try using [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Hope, this helps to you.

Comment: See it in the links. There're pretty useful examples.